# Send system unavailable message from the web app

Tags: jakarta-ee, runtime-error, error-code, http-status-code-503

Can a web app send a system unavailable message to the calling application when it becomes unavailable..? I know that the system goes in an indefinite state or unknown state to communicate back. But can there be an alternative without having to build a monitoring app for sending alerts..?

Answer (score 0):

The webapp pretty much by definition can't send anything when it's down.  But if you fronted the webapp server (i.e. Tomcat/Wildfly/etc.) with Apache then it's proxy could send the 503 as it's still running.